# How do I override loop template and show quantities next to add to cart buttons for a specific category or multiple products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have used the code below but this adds the quantity adjustment next to the add the cart button on every product. I only want it to appear on specific products or a single product category.  I have tried everything I can think of to call multiple products or the category and have failed. I am only a novice so that doesn't help. Any help would be appreciated.

```
/**
 * Override loop template and show quantities next to add to cart buttons
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually()) {
        $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
        $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
        $html .= '</form>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: You want to do this on the archive pages like `shop` and `category` ?  And you are asking to show the stock quantity or the input field where you choose the quantity?  That's what you say in your question, title, but not in the question.

Comment: It would be easier if you can re-format your code snippet.

Comment: I am open for anything as long as it achieves what I am looking for. The code I originally posted I like what it does however I only want it to apply to the category 'table-lamps' and nothing else.  Right now, that code adds the box to every product, every category.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were looking for based on the question as I read it. All I did was add if `(is_product_category('slug'))` and the `get_stock_quantity()` functions.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually()) {
        // use your category slug Choose multiples by using || is_product_category('your-slug')
        if (is_product_category('YOUR-SLUG-HERE')){ 
            $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
            $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
            $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
            // Wasn't sure if you wanted to show the quantity - but this is how
            $html .= '<span id="stockQuantity">'.$product->get_stock_quantity().'</span>';
            $html .= '</form>';
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I added your code but it did not do anything.  Let me rephrase my question. The code I originally posted I like what it does however I only want it to apply to the category 'table-lamps' and nothing else.

Comment: `if (is_product_category('YOUR-SLUG-HERE'))` Replace 'YOUR-SLUG-HERE' with your slug `table-lamps`

Comment: Thank you again for quick response. I did add my slug and still did not work.  Made no changes.

Comment: Please look at the code I used to make sure I am not missing anything. I placed a copy of code in a sperate answer to this thread\

Comment: You need to replace "YOUR-SLUG" with whatever your slug is... you can't leave 'your-slug' in there, unless that is the name of your slug.

Comment: add this code to your functions.php - I tested and it works.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and patience with me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I Entered into Snipets Plugin and it does not produce any results. Am I missing something????

add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually()) {
        // use your category slug Choose multiples by using || is_product_category('your-slug')
        if (is_product_category('table-lamps')){ 
            $html = 'add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
            $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
            $html .= '' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '';
            $html .= '';
        }
    }
    return $html;
}